# RVM default is 2.1.1 but 2.1.2 is loaded initially

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

When I run `rvm list` I get the following:

> rvm rubies
>
> ruby-1.9.2-p318 [ x86_64 ]
>   ruby-1.9.3-head [ x86_64 ]
>   ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
>   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
>   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
>
> =* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

Which would make me think that 2.1.1 is my default ruby version. However, when I open a new terminal window and run `ruby -v` I get

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

My .bash_profile doesn't do anything besides setting $PATH and a few other variables so I cannot understand why this is being set as such. Reason this is such an issue is that I have a Rakefile which loads my automation framework and I'd rather not specify setting the ruby version in that.

Comment: If you type `rvm use 2.1.1` or `2.0.0` does `ruby -v` change?  If not, RVM is not installed correctly.

Comment: **However, when I open a new terminal window and run ruby -v I get** Are you opening the new window in a different directory?

Comment: @NickVeys yes it does change

Comment: @7stud nope same directory but surely this shouldnt matter?

Comment: In your new terminal window, what do you get for `rvm list`?  From now on, with all commands, post your prompt as well, so we know what directory you are in.

Comment: Have you read and followed RVM's [installation directions](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) closely, including the "Troubleshooting Your Install" steps and the [Basics](http://rvm.io/rvm/basics) page? "My .bash_profile doesn't do anything besides setting $PATH and a few other variables" sounds suspicious as you *SHOULD* be doing more.

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question.

Comment: what is the output of ```$ which ruby```? ( in a new terminal )