# RVM: Can set the default ruby version but cannot set the current version

Tags: ruby, rvm

Problem: Though the default ruby is set to ruby 2.2.2. When I open a terminal ruby 2.2.1 is loaded. How do I ensure that ruby 2.2.2 loads when I open a new terminal.

Problem phrased differently: I am not able to set `current && default` to ruby 2.2.2 unless I uninstall ruby 2.2.1. This is what I get when I type `rvm list`

```
   ~ $ rvm list

    rvm rubies

       ruby-1.8.7-head [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
    => ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
     * ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]

    # => - current
    # =* - current && default
    #  * - default
```

I want the `current && default` to be ruby-2.2.2. If I type `rvm use default` I get the result as the following (which is what I want).

```
~ $ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

How can I make sure whenever I open a terminal the environment `current && default` is set to ruby 2.2.2 as shown above?
An observation:  If I uninstall ruby 2.2.1 it defaults to the above situation. I have some projects which need ruby 2.2.1 and I cannot do that.

What should I do about this?

By the way `which ruby` gives the following output:

```
~ $ which ruby
/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
```

Here is a similar question which has been unanswered:
[RVM default is 2.1.1 but 2.1.2 is loaded initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064252/rvm-default-is-2-1-1-but-2-1-2-is-loaded-initially)

Here is the out put of `rvm info`:

```
~ $ rvm info

ruby-2.2.1:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux X200 4.4.0-36-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 11:49:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/14.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 year 3 months 21 days 22 hours 56 minutes 31 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/rk/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.1p85"
    date:         "2015-02-26"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2015-02-26 revision 49769"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    ruby:         "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/rk/.rvm/bin:/home/rk/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/rk/android-studio/bin:/home/rk/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/home/rk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1"
    IRBRC:        "/home/rk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me following command doing the work

```
rvm --default use 2.2.2
```

You might have issue with login shell and required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/K0LSe  . I enabled the login shell through preferences long ago. Please look at it.

Comment: @ravikanth, yes, this should work perfectly, refer
`https://rvm.io/rubies/default`

Comment: @Chirag I tired that before. It did not work. There is some issue with rvm installation. I removed and reinstalled rvm.

Comment: @Ravikanth, do you get an error when you switch using `--default`
When you reinstalled RVM, was it a clean installation by removing all the previous RVM files?

Comment: @Chirag No. It is just that when I close and reopen a new terminal the default and current ruby versions are different. Once I reinstalled everything is back in place.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same issue by updating the .ruby-version file in the Rails app to the newer ruby version you're trying to use (2.2.2 in your case)